# Which sounds better: “What’s in ――” or “What’s on――”?

Tags: idioms, expressions, names, titles

I’m making the title of a web page with classifieds, and I’d like to name it either “What’s in (*town name*)” or “What’s on (*town name*)”.

Which one sounds better for a town classified web page?

Right now I'm thinking “What’s on (*town name*)” sounds more like for events or concert, so I’m thinking of going with “What’s in (*town name*)”.

Comment: This really depends what the web page would be advertising.  Events?  Items for sale?  Job vacancies?  Could the title maybe just be the town name, without any extra words in front?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What ‘sounds better’ is a matter of opinion. However, if you ask, for example, *What’s in Denver?* you’re asking what buildings, institutions, organsiations, entertainments and so on are in Denver. If you ask *What’s on Denver?* I don’t think many would understand the question. Are you perhaps trying to say *What’s on in Denver?* That would certainly cover concerts and similar events.

Comment: an alternative: "*What's On*: Denver" ([Feature Title]: [Subtitle])

Answer (score -1):

Occasionally, "on" makes sense when talking about features of a geographical area; "My family lives on Long Island" is an example: Long Island is usually preceded by "on" in those sentences (and you can usually tell when someone is not from Long Island when they say "in Long Island"). The reason for this is based on the type of object that the name asserts the area is: an island or a coast is something you're "on", while a village or city is something you're "in". So, most towns in the U.S. are not cases of such phenomenon, therefore "What's in TOWNNAME" would sound correct to people rather than "What's on TOWNNAME".

Though I did just realize/realise this is not a U.S.-exclusive site, my bad. Could be totally different overseas.